# Input string was not in a correct format C#

Tags: c#

Alright, I'm extremely new to programming so odds are this is a really easy fix but for some reason, I'm receiving an `Input string was not in a correct format error`. When I try to parse a string value from a file to double when I'm pretty sure the string being input is definitely a number that can be parsed to double. What's strange is that I checked the array and all the info gets placed into the array perfectly. So I really don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Here's the code for the method that I'm getting the error from:

I receive the error `Input string was not in a correct format` in the method `LoadArray()` at the line that says `annualInterestRate = Double.Parse(fields[0]);`.

This is the info I have in the input file in the same formatting:

```
.015 20000 w8v6754r6 Jacobs,Michael
.045 60000 w4fg55566 Ray,Bill
.035 40000 w6gyhygg7 Nichols,Luke
.018 25000 w5g55g777 Hendricks,Gary
```

The rest of the code from that class is just there in case, but really the problem is most likely in the `LoadArray()` method. Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace SavingsAccount
{
    class Driver
    {
        public static void LoadArray(SavingsAccount [ ] array)
        {
            string accountHolder = " ";
            string accountNumber = " ";
            double annualInterestRate = 0.0;
            double savingsBalance = 0.0;
            int i = 0;


            StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader("accountdata.txt");

            SavingsAccount account1 = new SavingsAccount();

            //set to default constructor
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                array[j] = new SavingsAccount();

            while (!inFile.EndOfStream)
            {


                //input file
                string[] fields = inFile.ReadLine().Trim().Split(' ');
                annualInterestRate = Double.Parse(fields[0]);
                savingsBalance = Double.Parse(fields[1]);
                accountNumber = fields[2];
                accountHolder = fields[3];


                //annualInterestRate = Double.Parse(inFile.ReadLine());
                //savingsBalance = Double.Parse(inFile.ReadLine());
                //accountNumber = inFile.ReadLine();
                //accountHolder = inFile.ReadLine();


                //set info from input file
                account1.setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
                account1.setAccountHolder(accountHolder);
                account1.ModifyInterestRate(annualInterestRate);
                account1.ModifySavingsBalance(savingsBalance);

                array[i] = new SavingsAccount(annualInterestRate, savingsBalance, accountNumber, accountHolder);
                i++;




            }//end while
            inFile.Close();
        }//end method

        public static void SavingsReport( SavingsAccount [ ] array)
        {
            SavingsAccount account1 = new SavingsAccount();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------Savings Report-----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Interest Rate   Savings Balance    Account Number    Account Holder");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(account1.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();
            //use array as parameter
        }

        public static void StoreAccounts( SavingsAccount [ ] array)
        {
            SavingsAccount account1 = new SavingsAccount();
            StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Juan D Sanchez\Desktop\accountholderdata.txt");
            //use array as parameter
            outFile.WriteLine("------------------------Savings Report-----------------------------");
            outFile.WriteLine("Interest Rate   Savings Balance    Account Number    Account Holder");
            outFile.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                outFile.WriteLine(account1.ToString());
            }

            outFile.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            outFile.WriteLine();

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            SavingsAccount[] Accounts = new SavingsAccount[100];

            LoadArray(Accounts);

            SavingsReport(Accounts);

            StoreAccounts(Accounts);



            //for (int i = 0; i < Accounts.Length; i++)
            //{

            //}
            //exits the program after the user enters any key
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.....");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }//end main

    }//end class
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what `fields` contains _before_ you do the split?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on that line and inspecting the contents of `fields`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your file and make sure there's no empty line at the end. Also make sure that fields are veing populated correctly.

I would add breakpoint at the line you are getting the error and go through line by line to find out what data is being passed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Solved! Haha, I cant believe it! All this time i spent looking through fields and what not and all it was that I had a couple of empty lines at the end of my input file! That's just ridiculous! Thanks a ton man for the help!

Comment: @user1210259 - Using the debugger would have significantly cut down the amount of time you spent looking through the fields. It is a developers best friend.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a culture problem. Try `double.Parse(fields[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a culture problem. I'm convinced his `accountdata.txt` does not contain what his code is assuming it contains.

Comment: @Fulvio: it can be. Go to your Visual Studio and try Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(".015")); You'll get that FormatException. Then, add the culture info. It parses correctly.

Comment: @M.Babcock You were pretty quick on your downvote without at least giving me time to edit my code based on your comment.

Comment: @Fulvio - I wasn't the downvoter. I merely pointed out the flaw in your code. It wasn't worth the -1 hit to downvote it.

Comment: Guys, please. This question is with, at least, 40 views. Anyone of them could be the downvoter.

Comment: When "25.53191489361702" is not parsing, it most certainly is a culture problem!!! Thanks for this!