# Input string was not in a correct format in a Formula

Tags: c#

I was try to create a formula that will calculate the total amount and show it in a textbox , but there's an error that says
   **" Input string was not in a correct format."**

```
private void txtQUANTITYPOS_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtTOTALPOS.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtPricePOS.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtQUANTITYPOS.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Can you help me please , thank you again in advance :)

Comment: Have you googled your question or should we do it for you?

Comment: Some of your TextBoxes seems to be not in 'double' format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input string was not in a correct format C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286319/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-c-sharp)

Comment: i googled it but i can't totaly understand and i tried trial and error , can you do it for me , please sir

Comment: It looks like the content of your textboxes do not contain numbers, maybe they contain empty string or other characters except numbers. You could use Double.TryParse instead

Comment: Check if decimal and thousands separators are the expected (dot vs. semicolon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible scenario - You may have enter a number in your txtQUANTITYPOS textbox but txtPricePOS textbox is still empty. Therefore, you probably getting this error because your txtPricePOS textbox doesn't contains a number yet.

You could use Double.TryParse instead to ensure your are not multiplying other character rather than numbers:

Following an example of how you could implement it:

```
    private void txtQUANTITYPOS_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double pricePos;
        double qtyPos;

        if (!double.TryParse(txtPricePOS.Text, out pricePos))
            return;  // Will return in case txtPricePOS.Text is not a number

        if (!double.TryParse(txtQUANTITYPOS.Text, out qtyPos))
            return;  // Will return in case txtPricePOS.Text is not a number

        txtTOTALPOS.Text = (pricePos * qtyPos).ToString();

    }
```

Comment: OMYYYYYYYYYY GHAD

Comment: ITS WORKING THANK YOU !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!